# Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:7

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

I just imported an Android project into Eclipse, and am getting the above error.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Care to post the fix and mark question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, simply go into Eclipse and click on the Android SDK Manager (the green android button with the down arrow just to the right of the print button).  Download the appropriate SDK.  In this instance it would be "Google APIs - 7".  Restart eclipse and then clean your project (Project -> Clean) if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

simply changing

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7">
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8">
```

in **mainfest.xml** will fix the problem